# 08 jetta 2.5 odd noise when turning left

Tags: noise

I`ve been stumped on an odd noise coming from the forward passenger wheel area when turning sharp left. I`ve inspected the area with and without the wheel mounted. Nothing loose or rubbing. I`ve changed the right hand forward axle,and the right hand forward wheel hub assy and it has a new set of tires. No help. I`ve even questioned the left forward wheel but it`s definitely coming from the right hand side. No vibration on the steering wheel. It sounds just like a tire rubbing on a mud flap or fender. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be the wheel barring as i had something similar and it was my wheel barring. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed the wheel hub on front passenger side. That includes the wheel bearing. No help. This noise has me baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an Astra H. The reason was a slipping stabilizer bar: The rubber mounts were loose, the bar slided lateraly and started rubbing against the frame body. Perhaps you should inspect the suspension

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the car is left hand drive, it would indicate some sort of bearing issue in that corner (turning left loads up the right hand side of the vehicle).

If it isn't wheel bearings, it could indicate wear in the outer or inner CV joints.